# Detecting changes in an API with Python

Tags: python, api, request, discord.py, minecraft

I'm trying to use discord.py to send a discord message when someone joins and leaves my Minecraft server using https://mcapi.us/. I need to detect when the number of players goes up or down and also collect their name to use in the message. Is this possible or should I try working in a plugin?

Here is what the API outputs:

```
"players":{"max":6,"now":1,"sample":[{"name":"resuther","id":"ccfb1ef4-da4a-442a-90d2-9d2c5fbe9d40"}]}
```

It updates every 30s or so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tradicional way to do it is using polling - fetch from the API every n seconds and look for changes. If you prefer a much better and elegant way I suggest you use the websocket protocol (if the API supports it)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Thanks, I will look into this.